# Round off to next 0.05 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, rounding

I have a requirement, where I need the rates to be rounded off to nearest nickel.
For e.g:

**Rate** . . . .     **Rounded Value**
1.90 . . . .  1.90
1.91 . . . .     1.95
1.92 . . . .     1.95
1.93 . . . .     1.95
1.94 . . . .     1.95
1.95 . . . .     1.95
1.96 . . . .     2.00
1.97 . . . .     2.00
1.98 . . . .     2.00
1.99 . . . .     2.00
2.00 . . . .    2.00

i.e if the **'hunderedth' place after decimal has to be rounded off to its next 0.05**.
I have written a query which gives me value *for nearest 0.05 not to next 0.05*.

```
select Rate, (Round((Rate)/0.25 , 2)*0.25) as RoundRate   from ProposedProductPrice order by created desc
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `ceiling`, it is basically a round up command. You can multiply by 20, since a nickel is 20th of a dollar - then divide back down by 20:

```
select ceiling(Rate * 20) / 20;
```

Comment: Cool! This is such a sweet and simple answer. Thanks Cato!